# How do I open open multiple Visual Studio Workspaces with a single shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have multiple `*.code-workspace` files on my desktop.

I want to move these files to another folder and then create a desktop shortcut that will launch all files from that folder with a single (double) click.

How do I do that?

Comment: On what OS is this?

Comment: @GinoMempin Windows 10